# Story ID - Recent Thriller, US Government, Middle East

Tags: identification-request

Good day to all, I have recently read a book, and I totally cannot remember the title of the book.

From what I recall, it’s a New York best seller and it’s quite popular.

Let’s go into the story of the book

It starts with a middle-aged man going into a sleazy bar and purchases a lap dance. He was enthralled by the dancer and followed her into an alley. After a kiss, this dancer killed the middle-aged man and the story jumps into the introduction.

An Irish woman who worked with the US government who wanted to do some good in the Middle East is suddenly called into the US President office to help with some investigation. The daughter of the US president was approached by some man through social media and told the president that over the next few days, he will release some dirty secrets about the US president.

Fast forward

The Irish woman continued to investigate and found out that the dancer was a new comer who started work on the day that the man died. It was revealed later that the man who died was the one who was leaking the secrets.

Fast forward

The president wanted the man dead and told his closest advisors that he wanted to kill that man but the president didn’t commit any orders to kill.

The end

Some parts of the story I am unable to remember. But please help me find out what is the name of the book and author. It’s killing me

Thanks very much in advance and have a pleasant day

Comment: Lets also go into what steps you have already taken to try and identify the book, what books came up in your searches that you dismissed as incorrect etc. Please see the story-identification tag Information Page https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for recommendations of detail to include.

Answer (score 3):

FOUND IT - YAY

It is the 2010 thriller, *[The Chosen One](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7829007-the-chosen-one)* by Sam Bourne.

> In the game of Washington politics, the stakes are as high as they get - and not everyone is prepared to play by the rules... Newly-elected US President Stephen Baker is flying high after signing a popular bill giving new rights to victims of domestic violence. But in Vic Forbes he has a ruthless enemy who is in possession of a crucial piece of knowledge that could destroy his career. When Forbes is found murdered the conspiracy theorists go into overdrive. Did the President order his killing, or was it his opponents? Ex-Presidential advisor Maggie Costello is called in to investigate. As she digs further she finds evidence of a conspiracy that reaches back into history and the heart of the US establishment...

Managed to find out the name of the book by some luck and brain scratching.

Thanks to all who read, edit and upvote and May you have a pleasant day ahead

Comment: Great! I'm glad you managed to solve it :-) Could you possibly **[edit] this answer to include more info, e.g. a link to or quote from a summary of the book?** That way, this Q&A might be useful to more people in the future: anyone else looking for the same book will immediately be able to see from your description that it's the right answer. (See also our [guidelines for a good story-ID answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/839/17).)

Comment: @Marcus: Also, you can accept your answer to your own question. You just have to wait at least 48 hours after asking.